# Writing tests for mailer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test a mailer send method which should only send mail to verified users.

So I have a method in my mailer like this :

```
def send_hints(user)
    @user = user
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Your hints for the day"
end
```

I'm trying to make sure that only verified users will receive this. So where user.verified_at is not null/nil.

Started writing test now:

```
describe "Emails should be sent only to verified user"
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, :verified_at => DateTime.now) }
  let(:mail) { UserMailer.send_hints(user) }
...
```

I'm not sure what would be smart to assert here? 
Like mail should be sent or should not be sent if I do it the other way around.

Comment: when is the email being sent? after user creation? after some action? you should test that, when that action is done with a verified user, UserMailer receives "send_hints" with user, and, on the same action, if the user is not verified, then UserMailer does not receive that method call. It's not clear WHEN it is happening to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to test it:

```
# config/environments/test.rb
YourApplication::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
end


# spec/your_spec.rb
describe 'Emails should be sent only to verified user' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, verified_at: verified_at) }
  before { UserMailer.send_hints(user) }
  subject { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to }
  context 'When the user is verified' do
    let(:verified_at) { DateTime.now }
    it { should include(user.email) }
    end
  end

  context 'When the user is not verified' do
    let(:verified_at) { nil }
    it { should_not include(user.email) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

action mailer is a terrible place to do any logic because it has this odd mix of class like methods, accessors that are not accessible on the instance, etc. write a presenter class that can check to see whether or not to send the mail in the first place and use that presenter class to do any of the specific representation of the user in the mailer. you can test the presenter then outside the notion of a mailer like you would a normal object.

```
class HintMailerPresenter
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def verified?
    user.whatever and whatever
  end
end

# in you controller/mail sending location

@presenter = HintMailPresenter.new(user)
Mailer.send_hints(@presenter).deliver if @presenter.verified?
```